# Read text file into list without using direct loop using std::list c++

Tags: c++, list, loops, iterator

I have a program that reads a list of assignments and removes the "bad" assignments, then writes into a new file. My function that removes the bad assignments works correctly. The code I currently am using to read the text file works correctly also, but is doing so with a while loop. How can I utilize the std::list library to accomplish the same thing without the while loop. Below is the code I am using for the removing of the bad assignmemnts (Prune) along with reading the text file.

```
void Prune()
{
    m_Assignments.remove_if([](const Assignment& assignment){ return !assignment.IsGood();});

}

void Read(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string s;

    std::getline(is, s);
    m_Name = s;

    Assignment a;
    while (is >> a)
    {
        m_Assignments.push_back(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to copy (using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)) strings from input stream to the list:

```
std::copy (
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{is}, 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}, 
    std::back_inserter(a)
);
```

Comment: this ended up working for me                    
                std::istream_iterator<Assignment> start(is);
  std::istream_iterator<Assignment> stop;
  std::copy(start,stop,std::back_inserter(m_Assignments));                    Thanks for helping me get on the right track!